# Elasticsearch DSL : Multiple aggregations

Tags: querydsl, elasticsearch

Shown below is the structure of type of my data.

```
 ArrivalAirport | DepartureAirport  | ArrivalDelay | DepartureDelay 
 A              | B                 |    2         |     5
 B              | C                 |    3         |     6
 C              | A                 |    4         |     7
 A              | B                 |    5         |     8
```

I want to perform together

1. aggregate on ArrivalAirport with average ArrivalDelay &
2. aggregate on DepartureAirport with average DepartureDelay.

What I am expecting as output to be something like:

```
 Airport | AverageArrivalDelay | AverageDepartureDelay 
 A       |        3.5          |        7
 B       |        3            |        6.5
 C       |        4            |        6
```

I am able do the two aggregations separately to get:

```
 ArrivalAirport | AverageArrivalDelay 
 A              |        3.5          
 B              |        3            
 C              |        4
```

by doing:

```
 "aggs": {
    "ArrivalAirport": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ArrivalAirport "
      },
      "aggs": {
        "AverageArrivalDelay ": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "ArrivalDelay"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and similarly for AverageDepartureDelay to get aggregation like this.

```
 DepartureAirport | AverageDepartureDelay 
 A              |        7          
 B              |        6.5            
 C              |        6
```

I am looking for a way in which **I would not have to merge the two results at application level**. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've based myself on the following mapping type:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "test1": {
      "properties": {
        "ArrivalAirport": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "DepartureAirport": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "DepartureDelay": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "ArrivalDelay": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And created four documents that match your data table above.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/tests/_bulk -d '
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 1}}
{"ArrivalAirport": "A", "DepartureAirport": "B", "ArrivalDelay": 2, "DepartureDelay": 5}
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 2}}
{"ArrivalAirport": "B", "DepartureAirport": "C", "ArrivalDelay": 3, "DepartureDelay": 6}
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 3}}
{"ArrivalAirport": "C", "DepartureAirport": "A", "ArrivalDelay": 4, "DepartureDelay":7}
{"index": {"_type": "test1", "_id": 4}}
{"ArrivalAirport": "A", "DepartureAirport": "B", "ArrivalDelay": 5, "DepartureDelay": 8}
'
```

The aggregation query that will return the results you expect would look like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/tests/_search -d '
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "Arrivals": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "ArrivalAirport": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Arrival": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "ArrivalAirport"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "AverageArrivalDelay": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "ArrivalDelay"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Departures": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "DepartureAirport": [
            "a",
            "b",
            "c"
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Departure": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "DepartureAirport"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "AverageDepartureDelay": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "DepartureDelay"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: thanks val, once again :). I was though trying to get a output json structure under a single aggregate object where with each key (with airport) has two values - AverageArrivalDelay and AverageDepartureDelay. Your query gives me two aggregate objects. This means again I need to post-process my results to be combined together. Though its not a bad way, but my application architecture is pushing me to minimize any processing at the client application.

Comment: I know there are new features coming in 2.0 that might help with this. In the meantime, another solution would be to change the mapping a bit and have something like airport: string, delay: int, arrival: boolean, unless you really need to keep the "relation" between arrival and departure airports in the same document (which would make sense if you were also storing the duration of the flight). With that modified mapping, we can create the results you expect.